# Laravel MixでJSをコンパイルさせる場合、id属性の良い命名規則はどんなものでしょうか？（Laravel Mixのベストプラクティスが知りたい）

Tags: laravel

Laravel 6.2 を使用しており、Laravel Mixについて勉強・試行錯誤中です。JSに関してはVue/Reactなどは使っておらず生JSかjQueryを使用しています。

LaravelのプロジェクトでLaravel Mixを使用して複数のJSファイルからビルド/コンパイルすると、productionの場合にはminifyされて高速化するなどの恩恵があるかと思いますが、複数のJSがひとつにまとまるので、よりHTML属性のid重複に気をつけて実装する必要があるのかなと考えています。
つまり、ページごとに asset() などでJSファイルを読み込む場合は、ひとつのページの中でのid重複に気をつければ良いですが、それらJSをまとめてMixする場合は「プロジェクト全体で」id重複に気をつける必要がある、と認識しているのですが、それは合っているでしょうか？（間違いでしたらすみません。）

classでDOMを操作したい時も同様ですが一応その前提で行くと、ページが増えるごとにどこでどんなidが使われているか見通しが悪くなったり別々なページでidが重複してしまったりすることを避けるために、idの命名がとても説明的で長いものになってしまいそうだと踏んでいるのですが、こちらの認識は合っているでしょうか。

短く命名する良いやり方があるか、命名の仕方ほか、そもそもの考え方や認識が間違っていないか、こうすると良いよというアドバイス等、もしLaravel Mixのベストプラクティス的なものをご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、お知恵を拝借できると嬉しいです。

Comment: どのようにIDを利用されているか分からないのでなんとも言えないのですが、SPAでもなくIDの重複が問題になるのは設計に問題があるような気もします。(View・ルートの識別子だというのであれば…いややはりそんなに問題にならないような) Laravel-mixを利用するにあたってエントリポイントは必ずしも1つである必要はありません。というか古典的なjQueryを多用するようなアプリケーションであればエントリポイントは分けたほうが書きやすい気はします。もちろん重複利用しているモジュールは適切にキャッシュさせられるようにできます。

Comment: @hinaloe 命名や設計の良い方法はさておき、エントリポイントを分けた方が良いんですね。こちらの回答をいただくまでエントリポイントが何なのかも知りませんでしたが、色々調べて勉強になりました、ありがとうございます。mix.js()のメソッドチェーンでページごとないしある程度のかたまりごと、JSのファイルは分けた方が良いというところまで理解しました。「重複利用しているモジュールは適切にキャッシュさせられる」というのは.version()によるバージョン化のことでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、当該部分、`version()`は当然として[`extract()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#vendor-extraction)などをうまく使う必要があるかもしれません。

Comment: @hinaloe ありがとうございます、extractメソッドですね。この辺り確認してみますmm　https://search.readouble.com/?query=6.x+extract